How to Pass Custom Parameters from SendGrid Email to Twilio Flex Task Attributes?
I'm working on an integration where incoming emails are processed through a webhook and then sent to the final recipients using SendGrid, with a corresponding task being created in Twilio Flex. My goal is to pass custom parameters with the email that can be used later within Twilio Flex for event streams and other workflows.
What I've Tried:
Using custom_args in SendGrid API: I included custom parameters in the custom_args field while sending the email through SendGrid, expecting these parameters to appear in Twilio Flex task attributes. However, they did not show up in the Flex Console.
Embedding Parameters in the Subject Line: As an alternative, I tried embedding custom parameters in the subject line, appending them in a JSON-like format. This worked to some extent but isn't ideal because it clutters the subject and requires additional parsing logic within Flex.
Example Code:
javascript
Copy code
const msg = {
    to: forwardTo,
    reply_to: { email: parsedMail.from.value[0].address },
    from: `${recipientAlias}@${process.env.domainName}`,
    attachments,
    text: parsedMail.text || " ",
    html: parsedMail.html || " ",
    subject: parsedMail.subject || " ",
    custom_args: {"check1": "check2"}
};

try {
    await sgMail.send(msg);
    console.log(`Email successfully sent to ${forwardTo} with subject: "${msg.subject}"`);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failed to send email:`, err.message);
}

Is there a better way to pass custom parameters from a SendGrid email to Twilio Flex that ensures these parameters are accessible in the Flex task attributes?
Are there any recommended best practices or alternative approaches for achieving this, perhaps something I haven't considered?
Thanks
